# Python: indexing excel spreadsheet to a dictionary

Tags: excel, python-3.x

i have a data sample in excel that i would like to be read in python and then exported to Json format.

Im having problems in finding a solution, you guys might help me with.

```
import xlrd
import json

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('myfile.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('test')

# read header values into the list
keys = [sheet.cell(1, col_index).value for col_index in range(sheet.ncols)]

print (keys)
dict_list = []
for row_index in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    d = {keys[col_index]: sheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value
         for col_index in range(sheet.ncols)}
    dict_list.append(d)

print (dict_list)

#create json out of the data above

with open('output.json','w') as fp:
    json.dump(dict_list, fp, indent=4,sort_keys=True)
```

This sample output works but it is not the desired result:
What i require:

```
['ID'] {1star, 2star, 3star} #headers
[1]    {1, 2, 3}
[2]    {14, 9, 6}
...
All rows of the xlsx
```

Is there a way to do this?
Im using Python 3.6

Im not an expert but i have tried several iterations without a positive result. Your feedback would be most welcome.

Current Data output: (in Python console).

```
['ID', '1 star', '2 star', '3 star']
[{'ID': 'ID', '1 star': '1 star', '2 star': '2 star', '3 star': '3 star'}, {'ID': 1.0, '1 star': 489850.0, '2 star': 979700.0, '3 star': 1469550.0}, {'ID': 2.0, '1 star': 979700.0, '2 star': 1959400.0, '3 star': 2939100.0}...
```

Json Output:

```
[
    {
        "1 star": "1 star",
        "2 star": "2 star",
        "3 star": "3 star",
        "ID": "ID"
    },
    {
        "1 star": 489850.0,
        "2 star": 979700.0,
        "3 star": 1469550.0,
        "ID": 1.0
    },
    {
        "1 star": 979700.0,
        "2 star": 1959400.0,
        "3 star": 2939100.0,
        "ID": 2.0
    },
    {
        "1 star": 1469550.0,
        "2 star": 2939100.0,
        "3 star": 4408650.0,
        "ID": 3.0
```

Comment: And what, since we aren't psychic and don't have your data file, are you actually seeing?

Comment: My apologies, i edited the question and provided an output sample of the data from the Console for you information. Thanks for your time to take a look at this, i appreciate it.

Comment: Managed to find a solution by using a Json structure to work as template, and populate the data as i required it.